# How to write test cases in React using Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am working on a React project. And I am very new in writing Jest test cases. In my project I wrote a simple function and trying to test that function. But the test case is failing someone please help to overcome all errors.

This is App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Add from './Add/Add';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-12'>
          <Add></Add>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

This is Add.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Add = () => {
    const addition = () => {
        const a = 10;
        const b = 10;
        const c = a + b
        return c
    }
    const myNumber = addition()
    return (
        <div>
            {myNumber}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Add
```

This is Add.test.js

```
import { addition } from './Add';

it('Addition testing', () => {
    expect(addition()).toBe(20)
})
```

If you have any questions please put a comment

Comment: Why addition is different component and it is returning empty `divs`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `addition` function is not exposed from `Add.js`. If you instead do

```
import React from 'react';

export const addition = () => {
    const a = 10;
    const b = 10;
    const c = a + b
    return c
}

const Add = () => {
    return (
        <div></div>
    )
}

export default Add
```

the test should pass.

If you want to use addition in your component you can do

```
import React from 'react';

export const addition = () => {
    const a = 10;
    const b = 10;
    const c = a + b
    return c
}

const Add = () => {
    const myNumber = addition();
    return (
        <div>{myNumber}</div>
    )
}

export default Add
```

Comment: Hi @Johan Book I tried your code but still it did not pass the test

Comment: What error does your test show? You probably need to use `it(...)` instead of `test()`

Comment: TypeError: (0 , _Add.addition) is not a function

Comment: Did you try running the corrected test with the code I added with `export const addition ...`?